# MySQL Multi users Transactions

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a hospital management system, as you know is a huge system, to make things clear, Reception will open a new ticket for the patient Ticket no will be a customized form month year no (112011000101) which mean ticket no 101 on the month Nov on 2011.

When saving the ticket, my application will read the last saved ticket no & increase the no with one, (Select Tick_No from tickets where Tick_No Like '112011'% order by Tick_No DESC limit 1), this will return the last saved ticket which is (112011000101) increment by one ==> new ticket will be (112011000102).

So if there are two employees saving new tickets in the same is there is a chance to get duplicate ticket no??

I'm using transactions with mysql database which will make a row-level locking but still table available for any queries.

so i need a clear answer please if it is possible.

note in my code, when saving if something go wrong a rollback will be issued and auto retry saving function will be issued (in each saving order the application will perform check for the last number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a table-level locking in this case, so you could use the `MyISAM` table engine. This should help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: I know but i need relational database, locking table will kill the benefits of using transactions.

Comment: How about doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the last ticket, and then adding the new line? this way online one user at a time can use the last number in order to make a new one.

Comment: OK, let's make it simpler, i want to know when using transactions if tow ticket with same number inserted to the tickets table mysql will rollback one of them, right??!! also at least one will be commented? is the answer yes?

Comment: If the ticket number is `UNIQUE`, then onely one of them will be commited and the other one will have to `rollback`.